# Bash: Screen parameters being interpreted incorrectly

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to start daemon screens with `screen -dmS nameofscreen command`. This works by itself, but when I use a command with `&&` or `|` it seems to interpret it wrong.

Example: `screen -dmS screen1 echo test && ls -al`

It seems to be interpreted as `(screen -dmS screen1 echo test) && (ls -al)` and I'm looking for it to be interpreted as `screen -dmS screen1 (echo test && ls -al)`.

How is this done? If I use () around the commands to be passed, screen doesn't accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses and `&&` and `||` are interpreted by the shell, not by screen. To get those operators to work in screen you need an explicit sub-shell.

```
screen -dmS screen1 sh -c 'echo test && ls -al'
```